# Is it a scoping problem?

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, forms, renewcommand, scoping

I try to display a fancy rating scale in pdf forms with the `hyperref` package. After
half a day of investigation, trying and errors, I finaly got something.
I use some redefinition of documented and undocumented `hyperref`'s macro (thanks stackexchange).

The following code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}


\newcommand{\radiosize}{1em}
\newcommand{\MakeScaleField}[2]{% label, field
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner sep=0,outer sep=0, label distance=2mm}]
   \node (chk) {#2};
   \node [anchor=east, label={[blue]left:\radiostart}] (a) at (chk.west) {A};
   \node [anchor=west, label={[blue]right:\radioend}] (b) at (chk.east) {B};
   \path [draw=blue, line width={\radiosize+6pt}, line cap = round] (a) -- (b);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\renewcommand{\LayoutChoiceField}[2]{% label, field
 \MakeScaleField{#1}{#2}
}

\newcommand{\formscale}[3]{% name start end
 \def\radiostart{#2}%
 \def\radioend{#3}%
 \let\radiocontent\empty%
   \foreach \i in {\radiostart,...,\radioend} {%
    \gappto\radiocontent{=}%
    \expandafter\gappto\expandafter\radiocontent\expandafter{\i}%
    \ifnum\i<\radioend \gappto\radiocontent{,}\fi%
   }%
 \renewcommand{\DefaultOptionsofRadio}{print,notoggletooff,borderwidth=1pt,bordercolor=white,width=\radiosize,height=\radiosize,bordersep=0pt}%
 \ChoiceMenu[ name=#1, radio, radiosymbol=6 ]{}{\radiocontent}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
 This is a scale from 1 to 6 :
 \formscale{Question}{1}{6}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

Gives me a quite convincing proof of concept :

[image: a scale with radio fileds]

The main caveat is that one cannot use default choice field after that.
I tried to move the `\renewcommand{\LayoutChoiceField}` in my `\formscale` command like I did with the `\renewcommand{\DefaultOptionsofRadio}` bu it failed badly.

The code :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}


\newcommand{\radiosize}{1em}
\newcommand{\MakeScaleField}[2]{% label, field
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner sep=0,outer sep=0, label distance=2mm}]
   \node (chk) {#2};
   \node [anchor=east, label={[blue]left:\radiostart}] (a) at (chk.west) {A};
   \node [anchor=west, label={[blue]right:\radioend}] (b) at (chk.east) {B};
   \path [draw=blue, line width={\radiosize+6pt}, line cap = round] (a) -- (b);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}


\newcommand{\formscale}[3]{% name start end
 \def\radiostart{#2}%
 \def\radioend{#3}%
 \let\radiocontent\empty%
   \foreach \i in {\radiostart,...,\radioend} {%
    \gappto\radiocontent{=}%
    \expandafter\gappto\expandafter\radiocontent\expandafter{\i}%
    \ifnum\i<\radioend \gappto\radiocontent{,}\fi%
   }%
 \renewcommand{\LayoutChoiceField}[2]{% label, field
  \MakeScaleField{#1}{#2}%
 }%
 \renewcommand{\DefaultOptionsofRadio}{print,notoggletooff,borderwidth=1pt,bordercolor=white,width=\radiosize,height=\radiosize,bordersep=0pt}%
 \ChoiceMenu[ name=#1, radio, radiosymbol=6 ]{}{\radiocontent}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
 This is a scale from 1 to 6 :
 \formscale{Question}{1}{6}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

Gives this useless thing :

[image: broken scale with no radio fields]

It look like the radio fields are not build anymore. I tried different things like redefining the `\MakeRadioField` command in my `\formscale` command but achieved nothing.

I don't know if this is something specific to the `hyperref` package or if i missed something obvious about scoping.

Comment: you need to double the # if you redefine inside another command: `\renewcommand{\LayoutChoiceField}[2]{\MakeScaleField{##1}{##2}}`

Comment: unrelated but be aware that the radio button code of hyperref is a bit faulty. See also https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/3

Answer (score 1):

While making some refinements, I found a solution using `let` instead of `renewcommand`.

**I still am eager to learn why my code above failed**

I can now save and restore modified commands in my `\formscale` command and then mix my "fancy" scales with other king of choice fields.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}


\newcommand{\radiosize}{1em}
\newcommand{\MakeScaleField}[2]{% label, field
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={inner sep=0,outer sep=0, label distance=2mm}]
   \node (chk) {#2};
   \node [anchor=east, label={[blue]left:\radiostart}] (a) at (chk.west) {A};
   \node [anchor=west, label={[blue]right:\radioend}] (b) at (chk.east) {B};
   \path [draw=blue, line width={\radiosize+6pt}, line cap = round] (a) -- (b);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}


\newcommand{\formscale}[3]{% name start end
 \def\radiostart{#2}%
 \def\radioend{#3}%
 \let\radiocontent\empty%
   \foreach \i in {\radiostart,...,\radioend} {%
    \gappto\radiocontent{=}%
    \expandafter\gappto\expandafter\radiocontent\expandafter{\i}%
    \ifnum\i<\radioend \gappto\radiocontent{,}\fi%
   }%
 \let\savedLayoutChoiceField\LayoutChoiceField%
 \let\LayoutChoiceField\MakeScaleField%
 \let\savedDefaultOptionsofRadio\DefaultOptionsofRadio%
 \renewcommand{\DefaultOptionsofRadio}{print,notoggletooff,borderwidth=1pt,bordercolor=white,width=\radiosize,height=\radiosize,bordersep=0pt}%
 \ChoiceMenu[ name=#1, radio, radiosymbol=6 ]{}{\radiocontent}%
 \let\DefaultOptionsofRadio\savedDefaultOptionsofRadio%
 \let\LayoutChoiceField\savedLayoutChoiceField%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
 This is a scale from 1 to 6 :
 \formscale{Question}{1}{6}

 \ChoiceMenu[ name=q2, radio ]{}{1,2,3}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

[image]